# Why is my Player Movement not working even though everything is fine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Now, I am new to unity, so a simple answer will help me a lot. I was working on a test platformer project. I was writing the player's movement script and I suppose it should be correct. But when I run the project, my player doesn't move at all. Any help will really be appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float vaxis;
    private float haxis;
    public float moveSpeed = 40f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 20f;
    private Vector2 newForce = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    public Rigidbody2D player;

     private void FixedUpdate()
     {
         haxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
         vaxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
         if(vaxis == -1)
             vaxis = 0;

         newForce.x = moveSpeed * haxis * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
         newForce.y = jumpSpeed * vaxis * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
         player.AddForce(newForce);
     }
 }
```

I have assigned the Rigidbody2D attached to my 'player' variable. I don't see any problem.
Please help me. This is really frustrating.

Thanks,
Nandan Goyal

Comment: Are `moveSpeed` and `jumpSpeed` correct? Is your `Rigidbody2D` maybe `isKinematic`? Does it have any constraints? Is it enabled? How are your axes configured? In general rather use `Time.deltaTime` also in `FixedUpdate`. Also try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code line by line and check all values.

Comment: Can you attatch a screenshot of the components in your player object

Comment: Maybe the objects `mass` or friction is too height for your inputs?

Comment: that's a pretty small force, try making it really big, like 40000, just to see if it works

Comment: Sorry for the late response guys. I want to thank you guys for being kind enough to help me solve my problem. Dunno's post was helpful. The force was too weak to move the player. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Ridgidbody is set to dynamic and not to kinematic, and have you attached the physics component?
hope that helps :)